# How can I order metaboxes in my posts in WordPress?

Tags: php, sql

hello i did add a custem filed and this is my code

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
function cd_meta_box_add()
{
    add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'المعلومات الرئيسية لفلل مشروع', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID , true);
    $text1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text1', true );
    $text2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text2', true );
    $text3 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text3', true );
    $text4 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text4', true );
    $text5 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text5', true );
    $text6 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text6', true );
    $textarea = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_textarea', true );
    $text7 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text7', true );
    $text8 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text8', true );
    $text9 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text9', true );
    $text10 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text10', true );
    $text11 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text11', true );
    $textarea2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_textarea2', true );
    $text12 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text12', true );
    $text13 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text13', true );
    $text14 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text14', true );
    $text15 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text15', true );
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text1">حالة المشروع</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text1" id="my_meta_box_text1" value="<?php echo $text1; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text2">الموقع</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text2" id="my_meta_box_text2" value="<?php echo $text2; ?>" />
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text3">مساحة الأرض</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text3" id="my_meta_box_text3" value="<?php echo $text3; ?>" />
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text4">مساحة البناء</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text4" id="my_meta_box_text4" value="<?php echo $text4; ?>" />
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text5">عدد الادوار</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text5" id="my_meta_box_text5" value="<?php echo $text5; ?>" />
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text6">عدد الغرف</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text6" id="my_meta_box_text6" value="<?php echo $text6; ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_textarea">المواصفات</label>
        <textarea name="my_meta_box_textarea" id="my_meta_box_textarea"><?php echo $textarea; ?></textarea>
    </p>
            <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text7">نوع الفيلا</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text7" id="my_meta_box_text7" value="<?php echo $text7; ?>" />
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text8">التشطيب ونوعية التصميم</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text8" id="my_meta_box_text8" value="<?php echo $text8; ?>" />
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text9">تأسيس المصاعد ويشمل</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text9" id="my_meta_box_text9" value="<?php echo $text9; ?>" />
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text10">تأسيس تمديدات التكييف ويشمل</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text10" id="my_meta_box_text10" value="<?php echo $text10; ?>" />
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text11">المسبح</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text11" id="my_meta_box_text11" value="<?php echo $text11; ?>" />
    </p>

        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_textarea2">الضمانات</label>
        <textarea name="my_meta_box_textarea2" id="my_meta_box_textarea2"><?php echo $textarea2; ?></textarea>
    </p>
            <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text12">ضمان المبنى - سنوات</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text12" id="my_meta_box_text12" value="<?php echo $text12; ?>" />
    </p>

        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text13">ضمان تمديدات الكهرباء - سنوات</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text13" id="my_meta_box_text13" value="<?php echo $text13; ?>" />
    </p>

        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text14">ضمان تمديدات السباكة - سنوات</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text14" id="my_meta_box_text14" value="<?php echo $text14; ?>" />
    </p>

        <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text15">ضمان المسابح - سنوات</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text15" id="my_meta_box_text15" value="<?php echo $text15; ?>" />
    </p>



    <?php   
}



add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // now we can actually save the data
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute

        )
    );

    // Probably a good idea to make sure your data is set
            if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text1'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900">حالة المشروع</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text1'], $allowed ) );
    if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text2'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/skins/1-default/Location-icon2.png" width="48" height="48" />الموقع</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text2'], $allowed ) );

            if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text3'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/skins/1-default/Location-icon.png" width="16" height="48" />مساحة الأرض</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text3'], $allowed ) );
            if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text4'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/skins/1-default/city_area.png" width="48" height="48" />مساحة البناء</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text4'], $allowed ) );
            if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text5'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/skins/1-default/New-room-icon.png" width="48" height="48" />عدد الغرف</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text5'], $allowed ) );
            if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text6'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/skins/1-default/office-building-icon.png" width="48" height="48" />عدد الأدوار</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text6'], $allowed ) );

    if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_textarea'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/skins/1-default/mowasafat-icon.png" /><br />', esc_attr( $_POST['my_meta_box_textarea'] ) );
                    if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text7'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/images/grid-small-dot-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />نوع الفيلا</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text7'], $allowed ) );
                    if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text8'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/images/grid-small-dot-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />التشطيب ونوعية التصميم</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text8'], $allowed ) );
        if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text9'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/images/grid-small-dot-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />تأسيس المصاعد ويشمل</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text9'], $allowed ) );
        if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text10'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/images/grid-small-dot-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />تأسيس تمديدات التكييف ويشمل</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text10'], $allowed ) );
        if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text11'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/images/grid-small-dot-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />المسابح</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text11'], $allowed ) );
            if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_textarea2'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/skins/1-default/damanat-icon.png"/><br />', esc_attr( $_POST['my_meta_box_textarea2'] ) );
        if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text12'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/images/grid-small-dot-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />ضمان المبنى - سنوات</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text12'], $allowed ) );
        if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text13'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/images/grid-small-dot-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />ضمان تمديدات الكهرباء - سنوات</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text13'], $allowed ) );
        if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text14'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/images/grid-small-dot-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />ضمان تمديدات السباكة - سنوات</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text14'], $allowed ) );
        if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text15'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/images/grid-small-dot-icon.png" width="16" height="16" />ضمان المسابح - سنوات</font>', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text15'], $allowed ) );

}
```

i have 2 problems

th first one it cant be edit because it become an empty value after saving

and the secode problem that it dosent apear by the way it order in code

the order become sooooo bad in posts

the first meta become the second and the 5 become 10

and the order soooo bad

i am so sorry for my bad english but i really need help in this please : (

and i am going crazy i dont know how i do fix meta order inside posts

Comment: What order do you expect to get? What is the order supposed to be based upon? Where do you expect to see this ordering?

Comment: i think you didnt understand me now i did write meta with this order  in the code in my post > i want it apear as the same order inside the post but it is not happend it become random in the pots !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> i did write meta with this order in the code in my post > i want it
>   apear as the same order inside the post

I think what that means is that you want the output order on the front end to match the order that you establish here:

```
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID , true);
$text1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text1', true );
$text2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text2', true );
$text3 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text3', true );
$text4 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text4', true );
$text5 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text5', true );
```

Or here:

```
<p>
    <label for="my_meta_box_text1">حالة المشروع</label>
    <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text1" id="my_meta_box_text1" value="<?php echo $text1; ?>" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="my_meta_box_text2">الموقع</label>
    <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text2" id="my_meta_box_text2" value="<?php echo $text2; ?>" />
</p>
```

The order that something goes into the database does is not order that it comes out because there is no intrinsic order to items in the database. You have to ask for those items in such a way that you get them in the order that you need them. You are going to have to do something like this:

```
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID , true);
$text1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text1', true );
$text2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text2', true );
$text3 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text3', true );
$text4 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text4', true );
$text5 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text5', true );
$text6 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text6', true );
```

All over again and print things in the order that you want.

Another option would be to use [`get_post_custom`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom):

```
$mbt = get_post_custom();
echo $mbt['my_meta_box_text1'];
echo $mbt['my_meta_box_text2'];
echo $mbt['my_meta_box_text3'];
```

Upon still further investigation I started to wonder if the problem isn't in the save function. Your save function does look strange. `update_post_meta` should look like this:

```
update_post_meta(
  $post_id, 
  $meta_key, 
  $meta_value, 
  $prev_value
);
```

Instead, you have this:

```
update_post_meta( 
  $post_id, 
  '<font color="#900"><img src="http://milleniumhouses.com/manazelelalfya/wp-content/themes/manazelelalfya/skins/1-default/Location-icon2.png" width="48" height="48" />الموقع</font>', 
  wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text2'], 
    $allowed 
  ) 
);
```

That second argument should be the `meta_key`-- the same key you are using to try to retrieve the values-- `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text2', true );`. Instead, you have that long string containing markup. I am honestly not even sure what you are trying to do with that but it not going to work with the rest of your code. The keys don't match. Plus, that string is going to get [truncated at 255 characters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_postmeta). That is not the way to save the data. It should be, for that example:

```
update_post_meta( 
  $post_id, 
  'my_meta_box_text2', 
  wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text2'], 
    $allowed 
  ) 
);
```

Comment: the same problem :(

Comment: it dosent solve

Comment: Yes, it does, or your real question is different than the one you asked.

Comment: no it is the same question and you r really undersnatnd me very well and i am very thankful for your help but your first solve < you can back to my code i am allreay did it but the meta apear random and your second solve i tried it but the meta dosent apear , this is the code i use to GET MY meta i will writ it in the second comment

Answer (score 0):

```
                        <?php
$ck = get_post_custom_keys($post_id); //Array
    foreach ($ck as $k) {
         if (substr ($k, 0, 1) == '_')
         {   // skip keys starting with '_'
             continue;
         }
         $cv = get_post_custom_values($k, $post_id );  //Array
            foreach ($cv as $c) {
                if (empty ($c))
                {   // skip empty value
                    continue;
                }

                echo ($k . ': ' . $c . '<br/>');
            }
    }

?>
```

Comment: look to my answer this is the code i use to get the meta so when i tried your second slove it is dosent apear so i used my code and edit it to use your idea but it is the same problem i dont know whats wrong with my stupid meta data < because it was great and become random without any reason :(

Comment: ok i solve it from my sql data bas > but now i have another problem with saving < the value come embty after saving so i cant back to edit it !! in the edit i need to writ all the value from the beginig